# Can I render a graph template in flask and save to PDF?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, pdf

It is not very clear for me if I can save a generated chart graphics to PDF.

I have the following case, I have and endpoint that returns a json and i want to generate graphics and tables from that, and after than to make a PDF.

The source of everything (endpoint, webpage) are on the same server. I would like to avoid opening another page and print to pdf from there.

Here is the code that takes the json from endpoint and create what i want to save to PDF.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Local request</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=297mm, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <style>
        .canvas {
            max-width: 297mm;
            max-height: 297mm;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            display: block;
            break-inside: avoid;
            page-break-inside: avoid;
        }

        table, th, td {
            text-align: center;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        th {
            background-color: grey;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<h1 style="text-align: center">XPF REPORT</h1>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
<div class="canvas">
    <h2 style="text-align: left;">PRI par IC et par etape</h2>
    <canvas id="PRIParICEtParEtape"></canvas>
</div>
<p><br></p>
<div class="canvas">
    <center>
        <h2 style="text-align: left;">PRI par IC et par etape / table</h2>
        <table width="300px">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>IC</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="icTableBody">
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td>Total:</td>
                <td id="totalSum"></td>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </center>
</div>

<div><p><br></p></div>
<div class="canvas">
    <h2 style="text-align: left;">PRI par DSP et par etape</h2>
    <canvas id="PRIParDSPEtParEtape"></canvas>
</div>
<script>

    
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {
        fetchData('http://localhost:8069/xpf_report')
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                PRIParDSPEtParEtape(data);
                PRIParICEtParEtape(data);
                createICTable(data);

            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching data:', error));
    });

    function createICTable(data) {
        const icTableBody = document.getElementById('icTableBody');
        const totalSumElement = document.getElementById('totalSum');
        const icTotalSum = {};

        data.forEach(lead => {
            const icName = lead.user.name;
            const expectedRevenue = lead.expected_revenue;
            if (!icTotalSum[icName]) {
                icTotalSum[icName] = 0
            }
            icTotalSum[icName] += expectedRevenue;
        });

        let totalSum = 0;

        Object.keys(icTotalSum).forEach(icName => {
            const row = document.createElement('tr');
            const icCell = document.createElement('td');
            const totalCell = document.createElement('td');
            icCell.textContent = icName;
            totalCell.textContent = icTotalSum[icName].toLocaleString('fr', {useGrouping: true});
            row.append(icCell);
            row.append(totalCell);
            icTableBody.appendChild(row);
            totalSum += icTotalSum[icName];
        });

        totalSumElement.textContent = totalSum.toLocaleString('fr', {useGrouping: true})
    }

    function PRIParICEtParEtape(data) {
        const userStageSum = {};

        data.forEach(lead => {
            const userName = lead.user.name;
            const stage = lead.stage.stage;
            const expectedRevenue = lead.expected_revenue;

            if (!userStageSum[userName]) {
                userStageSum[userName] = {};
            }

            if (!userStageSum[userName][stage]) {
                userStageSum[userName][stage] = 0;
            }

            userStageSum[userName][stage] += expectedRevenue;
        });

        const ctx = document.getElementById('PRIParICEtParEtape').getContext('2d');
        const userNames = Object.keys(userStageSum);
        const stages = [...new Set(data.map(lead => lead.stage.stage))];

        const datasets = stages.map(stage => ({
            label: stage,
            data: userNames.map(userName => userStageSum[userName][stage] || 0),
            borderWidth: 1
        }));

        new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: userNames,
                datasets: datasets
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    x: {
                        type: 'category',
                        stacked: true,
                        ticks: {
                            color: 'black',
                            order: []
                        }
                    },
                    y: {
                        stacked: true,
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        ticks: {}
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }


    async function fetchData(apiUrl) {
        const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
        return await response.json();
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can put the context you want in the PDF in a "div" in a modal and generate pdf using that content inside div. Close the modal after download.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, sorry English is not my native language. The problem is how do I create PDF with charts directly from endpoint?